# How quickly can we calculate $k^2 \bmod p$?

Tags: algorithms

If we are working with a [residue number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_number_system) and start with $k$ such that $0 \le k < p$, **how quickly can we find $n$ such that $0 \le n < p$ and $n \equiv k^2 \bmod p$**?  We know, additionally, that $p$ is prime.

I'd prefer to use as little "memory" or space as possible, but I won't reject something that seems to use it efficiently.  Sorry I can't be more precise than this, but I'm just trying to get a good algorithm.

---

**SOME IDEAS**

We know that $k^2$ is equal to the sum of the first $k$ odd naturals.

There are (at most) two such numbers that, when squared, equal $n$ for some $k$, as shown in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237352/how-many-squares-can-be-congruent-modulo-a-prime).

Comment: Multiplication is pretty efficient. Are you sure that you want to find the **square** of $k$? Maybe you are trying to find the **square roots** of $n$ modulo $p$, when they exist.

Comment: @André Nicolas: I am trying to find the **square** of a big number, $k$, modulo another big number, $p$. I'm looking into speeding up integer operations for large integers, and I have some ideas on how to speed things up using squares.

Comment: Interestingly, in the *very* old days, there were tables of half squares or quarter squares, and people would find $xy$ by using $(x+y)^2-x^2-y^2$, or $(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2$.

Comment: That's sort of an idea that I have.  I'm trying to find results of larger multiplications via constructions of squares.  I guess there are more efficient routes nowadays, but I am really interested in the approach with squares anyways.  I'm trying to match it up with some new techniques.

Comment: How fast of an algorithm are you looking for? Standard multiplication, then reduction $\mod p$ will give something like $O(\log^2 p)$ time. Using Karatsuba or Toom-Cook will get that a bit faster, but you can't hope for better than $O(\log p)$.

Comment: I'm looking for something as fast as possible. I _was_ hoping for close to $O(\log p)$, but I realize that that may not be possible. I'm aware of Martin Fürer's algorithm, but I was wondering if it may be possible to do better using squares and not having to convert to residues.

Comment: Is $p$ fixed? If that is the case, perhaps [Montgomery multiplication](http://class.ece.iastate.edu/tyagi/cpre681/papers/montgomeryBuell.pdf) may turn out to be relevant.  
[Reference 2](http://www.mersennewiki.org/index.php/Montgomery_multiplication). From what I recalled, this is good when you are doing a lot of arithmetic modulo the same number. Perhaps you can find some way to improvise if not directly relevant.

Comment: @Yong Hao Ng: $p$ is fixed. I'm looking into this. Thank you very much for the references!

Comment: @Yong Hao Ng: This does look promising.  I would accept this as an answer if you want to anser the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting comment into a proper answer:

In modular arithmetic, [Montgomery Multiplication](http://www.mersennewiki.org/index.php/Montgomery_multiplication) ([ref. 2](http://class.ece.iastate.edu/tyagi/cpre681/papers/montgomeryBuell.pdf)), is a commonly used way to reduce the times one has to do modular reduction (a "mod $n$" operation).
The original paper can be found [here](http://archive.lucares.org/paper/Montgomery%20-%20Modular%20multiplication%20without%20trial%20division.pdf).

This applies when many mod $n$ operations are done on the same $n$.
A typical example would be modular exponentiation: $x^k\equiv y(\text{mod }n)$.
This is usually done using a [Binary Exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) method, involving approximately $log_2(k)$ modular reductions.
In such cases, using Montgomery Multiplication only 1 modular reduction is needed instead.

One may find actual applications in multi-precision libraries like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) and [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/).
The function is mpz_powm(), which does an exponentiation modulo $n$.
This is typically referred to as the "Montgomery's REDC" method.

The REDC algorithm requires some precomputation, which is why the method is only beneficial if multiple modular reduction is involved.

In this question, many squarings are done based on the same modulo reduction (mod $p$) and hence this suggestion.